# Expo-Vector-Icons show up on my Snack but are showing as question mark or Chinese character in the Android built app

Tags: android, react-native, expo

I am importing the files correctly as mentioned in documentation. I checked the package.json if it includes any old dependency that can lead to this error but I am not finding it. I will include here my package.json dependencies. The app also starts at app.js not main or anything else. I tried removing the @expo/vector-icons, but it gives an error when building for android (expo build:android) 'Missing @expo/vector-icons. The problem is still persisting and I am not getting the icons but just X symbols.

```
"@expo/vector-icons": "^10.0.3",
"expo": "^33.0.0",
"expo-asset": "^5.0.1",
"expo-constants": "^5.0.1",
"expo-font": "^5.0.1",
"haversine": "1.1.1",
"lodash": "4.17.11",
"pretty-ms": "4.0.0",
"prop-types": "15.7.2",
"react": "16.8.3",
"react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-33.0.0.tar.gz",
"react-native-compress": "2.0.1",
"react-native-elements": "0.19.1",
"react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "0.8.0",
"react-native-vector-icons": "5.0.0",
"react-navigation": "^3.0.0",
"react-navigation-material-bottom-tabs": "0.1.2"
```

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score -1):

**My environment:**

`"react-native": "0.62.1"`

`"react-native-elements": "^1.2.7"`

**Also:** My app is created and managed with React Native CLI

To make the menu icon to work correctly (it was displaying weird characters instead of `menu` item), I had to manually link the vector icons using:

`react-native link react-native-vector-icons`

If you get 'react-native not recognized....', try below:

`npx react-native link react-native-vector-icons`